# SharePoint 2013 site template w/content search web parts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a site template that uses content search web parts and I select a different control and item templates for that content search web part.

[image]

When I save the site as a template and create a new site using that template, the site does not have the correct templates - it appears the default templates are applied.  I pulled the site template into visual studio, and the settings I have set are indeed correct in the Elements.xml file.  So why are these settings reverting back to the default values when I create a new site based on this site template and how can I make it hang onto my values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/6938ccd0-ac29-4698-8a50-e40633614449